# XML Non Breaking White Space

Tags: php, mysql, xml, whitespace, xmlwriter

I think the cause of my woes at present is the non-breaking white space.

It appears some nasty characters have found their way into our MySQL database from our back office systems. So as I'm trying to run an XML output using PHP's XMLWriter, but there's loads of these silly characters getting into the field.

They're displayed in *nano* as `^K`, in *gedit* as a *weird square box*, and when you delete them manually in MySQL they don't take up a phsyical space, despite that you know you've deleted something.

Please help me get rid of them!

Here is the line that is the nightmare at present (i've skipped out the rest of the XMLWriter buildup).

```
$writer->writeElement("description",$myitem->description);
```

Comment: Where do you want to get rid of them?

Comment: getting rid inside MySQL would be awesome but changing encoding doesn't seem to get rid of them.. all I need really is them to be removed before they're output to the XML file

Comment: Please add the script where you build the XML file. Additionally, do you know what `^K` stands for in nano? Please link the specification for these characters in nano.

Comment: Added the problem line up, the rest is just standard php XMLWriter build, can't find a any reference for nano with the ^K, I presume that being down to it being an illegal character

Comment: Can you please verify that it's illegal and not just some non-printable character (as I assume because if you delete it, you describe that the operation is invisible in MySQL)? And can you be more specific in which sense it is illegal? What are legal characters? What encoding is used?

Answer (score 0):

After you have identified which character specifically you want to remove (and it's binary sequence), you can just remove it. For example with [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$binSequence = "..."; // the binary representation of the character in question
$descriptionFiltered = str_replace($binSequence, '', $myitem->description);
$writer->writeElement("description", $descriptionFiltered);
```

You have not specified yet about which concrete character you're talking, so I can't yet specify the binary sequence. Also if you're talking about a group of characters, the filtering might vary a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that they are [vertical tabs](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html), ASCII x0B. You should be able to `REPLACE` them in MySQL:

```
SELECT REPLACE('\v', '', `value`) WHERE key = 'foo';
```

However, [the official reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html#character-escape-sequences) doesn't mention `\v` specifically. If it doesn't work, you can remove it afterwards in PHP with a simple str_replace (since PHP 5.2.5):

```
str_replace("\v", '', $result);
```